# Bash script Request body is un-json-able

Tags: json, bash, api, sh

Im trying to push a data to an API,
 for which I get the below error:

```
("Request body is not unjson()-able: %s" % body)
DirectException: Request body is not unjson()-able: '{"action":"EventsRouter","method":"add_event","data":[{"summary":"mes","device":"hos","message":"message","component":"sev","severity":"ap","evclasskey":"nxlog","evclass":"nxlog","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}'
```

current bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
message=$1
hostname=$2
appname=$3
severity=$4

data='{"action":"EventsRouter","method":"add_event","data":[{"summary":"'$message'","device":"'$hostname'","message":"message","component":"'$appname'","severity":"'$severity'","evclasskey":"nxlog","evclass":"nxlog","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}'

echo "Total number of args : $#"

echo "message = $message"
echo "hostname = $hostname"
echo "appname = $appname"
echo "data = $data"

curl -u "Eve:eve@123" -k "https://myurl.com/zport/dmd/evconsole_router" -d "'$data'" -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

First, What is the reason and how can i correct this. I am only sending simple values while testing:

```
sh tcp.sh mes hos sev ap
```

However, when i curl a data directly, it is working.

```
curl -u Eve:eve@123 -k https://myurl.com/zport/dmd/evconsole_router -d '{"action":"EventsRouter", "method":"add_event","data":[{"summary":"test","device":"test","message":"msg","component":"testhost","severity":"5", "evclasskey":"nxlog", "evclass":"/nxlog/perf","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"

{"uuid": "1654584c-5f86-489e-a5e7-35d45e462066", "action": "EventsRouter", "result": {"msg": "Created event", "success": true},"tid": 2, "type": "rpc", "method": "add_event"}
```

Secondly, This is about to be automated to read multiple log messages, if the log message has special characters such as ',",\,/, etc, will it affect my bash inputs?
If yes, how to I eliminate it?

Comment: What is the point of enclosing `$data` in single quotes? `'{...}'` is not a valid JSON value.

Comment: It is actually, when i directly curl it, the data is passing through. @oguzismail

Comment: No, it is not. If the server you're sending that request to is broken, we can't help much here.

Comment: I have added the curl output in the question, where the data parsing is successful, please check. @oguzismail

Comment: I saw that in your previous question. The JSON value you sent in that request is not enclosed in single quotes. `curl -d 'value' ...` and `curl -d "'$value'" ...` are not the same

Comment: Should i try a single quote only? @oguzismail

Comment: I probably should, Im sorry, Im not very versed in bash, trying to get there :) I will try around with it. Thanks! @oguzismail

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this syntax and check the execution

```
data=$(cat <<EOF
{"action":"EventsRouter","method":"add_event","data":[{"summary":"$message","device":"$hostname","message":"message","component":"$appname","severity":"$severity","evclasskey":"nxlog","evclass":"nxlog","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}
EOF
)
```

> Curl command syntax like

```
curl -u "Eve:eve@123" -k "https://myurl.com/zport/dmd/evconsole_router" -d "$data" -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```